# Statistics and information about large SharePoint farms

Tags: sharepoint, architecture, farm

I'm looking for informations and statistics about large SharePoint farms. Who runs such a farm? How many users do they have? How many documents do they manage/store? What does the farm architecture look like?

To put it bluntly, what is SharePoint able to manage?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you looking for a case study as to SharePoint scalability?  Take a look at the SharePoint Server Scalability and Performance whitepaper (http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=120901) which covers a scenario with 50 Million content items uploaded into SharePoint.